# different div sizes on browser resize

Tags: css, html, layout, responsive-design

I have 2 divs that are side by side that make up part of my responsive design

I have each div set at a height of 179 because there was a gap under one of the divs and a suggestion was to give them set heights.

When there isnt enough room the divs stack but then the page content gets pushed down further than id like.

Is there any way to keep the divs at the same size as each other when there is room but the right one to end up being only a certain height say 20px rather than 179px when the browser is resized and there isnt enough room for both divs and they stack?

Im hoping theres an answer other than using media queries

`

```
</div>
<div class="right-column1">

</div>
</div>


.container1 {
width: 100%;

}
.left-column1 {
width: 50%;
float:left;
height:179px;
}
.right-column1 {
width:50%;
float:left;
height:179px;
}`
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, can you give us a link of your problem? you can use jsfiddle or other free hosts, thanks!

Comment: I basically just want the right div to go from 179 to 20px height when the browser becomes to small to hold the left and right div and they stack

Comment: Because the right div only contains a search box and takes up to much screen space when they stack on smaller screens or browser sizes but in full size browsers and screens they both are 179px because it would look weird if they were 2 different heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible with CSS alone.

I've done it in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YAFdz/) - I'm not sure if it will work for you.

JS

```
var $startwindowwidth = $( window ).width();

$( window ).resize(function() {
  if ( $( window ).width() < ( $startwindowwidth * 0.5 ) )
  {
      $( '.right-column1').css({
          'float'  : 'none',
          'height' : '20px'
                                });
      $( '.left-column1').css({
          'float'  : 'none'
                                });
  } else {
      $( '.right-column1').css({
          'float'  : 'left',
          'height' : '179px'
                                });
      $( '.left-column1').css({
          'float'  : 'left'
                                });
   }
});
```

---

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/YAFdz/2/.

Don't give it a height, and you can center it by putting in a div.

But keep in mind that when you start putting "fixed" width info into the div, it
won't be "fluid".

Comment: could i set the background color the same for the container and only have the right div to the size of the search box if i have the search box centered vertically? ive tried but when the left and right divs stack the search box dissapears

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - are you changing the initial layout before the window changes size?

Comment: well the right div would always be set at the size of the search box. say 20px high and would be centered vertically in the container. so it would look as if it was the same size as the left div because of the background color of the container. so when left and right stack on browser shrink, the right div would only take up 20px rather then 179 and the page content wouldnt be hidden below 2 197px divs.

Comment: Ok i see its js. Would that be cross browser/device compatible?

Comment: I forgot to mention i have media queries to control my responsive layout. Do you think it would work alongside them?

Comment: I don't know about cross-browser compatibility - download the browsers and try it. Try it next to your media queries and see if it works.

Comment: Ok will do thankyou. Am i putting the right divs content in the right-column or sizediv?

Comment: sizediv as its 20px as i asked ok its late and im tired lol. When i put my google search box in the sizediv it appears underneath it, any ideas? The search box has its own div with only a width of 100%

Comment: hey do you know why my content comes out of the div?

Comment: probably a sizing issue. Change the size of the content, or size of the div.

Comment: What are you putting in the div?

Comment: Given this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/YAFdz/3/ - you're probably not going to be able to fit it into your criteria because the input element is fixed and you need a certain size for the button. You may have to rethink your setup.

Comment: the button is inline with the search box http://www.techagesite.com/page-1work11122.htm it doesnt matter if the sizwdiv is a little higher than i originally wanted. is the any way to do it with the current setup?

Comment: It looks like the Google custom search form is not in the right-column1 div.

Comment: its in the box3 which is my layouts equivalent of right column div. the css is all the same in the external stylesheet

Comment: its in box 3/sizediv/searchbox

Comment: what i mean is sizediv is inside box3 and then the search is in sizediv

Comment: ive got the searchbox now showing in the sizediv rather than underneath it but theres still the issue of the sizediv being way too high. For the life of me i cant figure out why when its size is set at 25px. So what i end up with is the searchbox being centered and having unneeded space above and below it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a media query to change the style of the right column when the size of a screen gets to small. For example, if you wanted the two divs to be the same size up until the viewport was less than 200px (at which point the right column would obtain a height of 40px), you could use the following:

```css
#left , #right{
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}


#left{
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}


#right{
  float: right;
  background-color: orange;
}

@media (max-width: 200px){
#left{
  width: 100%;
}


#right{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
  
}
```

```html
<html>
   <body>
       <div id="left"><p>Left</p></div>
       <div id="right"><p>Right</p></div>
   </body>
</html>
```